# How to GROUP BY WorkDept and Sex combined

Tags: mysql, sql, database, db2

"Joe's manager wants information about employees grouped by department,
grouped by sex and in addition **by the combination of department and sex**. List only
those who work in a department which start with the letter D.
List the department, the sex, sum of the salaries, minimum salary and maximum
salary."

So basically, I need 3 groups.
But I can't seem to have a GROUP BY WorkDept and Sex combined.

This doesn't work for me:

```
    SELECT WORKDEPT, SUM(SALARY) AS SALARY_SUM, MIN(SALARY) AS MIN_SALARY,
  MAX(SALARY) AS MAX_SALARY
  FROM EMPLOYEE
  WHERE WORKDEPT LIKE 'D%'
      GROUP BY CUBE(WORKDEPT, SEX);
```

THANK YOU!

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating the problem. If you `GROUP BY workdept, sex` you'll get all the men in Dept. X, followed by the women in Dept. X, followed by the men in Dept. Y &c. &c. I can't picture how else you even *could* slice the data at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think others are right that you may be overcomplicating the problem.  However, if you intend on using `cube`, then try `with cube`.  Like this...

```
select 
    WORKDEPT, 
    sum(SALARY) as SALARY_SUM, 
    min(SALARY) as MIN_SALARY, 
    max(SALARY) as MAX_SALARY

from EMPLOYEE

where WORKDEPT LIKE 'D%'

group by WORKDEPT, SEX 
with cube
```